# Techniques to study sums over prime divisors

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

What techniques could one use to study functions that are sums that require knowledge of the prime decomposition of the function's argument? For example, if one wanted to study the following general sum
$$f(n) = \sum_{p\mid n}\frac{g(p)}{p}$$
You can assume $f, g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ if needed. What specific techniques could one use here? When the sum runs over $n$'s divisors there seem to be a lot of ways one could approach this, but using only $n$'s prime factors seems to render things for example requiring the Möbius function or certain concolutions as useless here. It's a hassle to have to figure out the prime decomposition of $n$, and doesn't allow for a general study of $f(n)$ which is why I'm asking this here. I'm aware of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_sum_identities#Sums_over_prime_divisors) Wikipedia page section, but I don't find that it answers what I'm looking for. Any help is appreciated!

---

I know there are plenty of techniques for looking at sums over the all the primes, or sets of consecutive primes, but to clarify my question is very specifically sums over prime divisors of a number

Comment: So aliquot sums related?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Not directly as far as I’m aware…

Comment: Without specifying what "general study of $f(n)$" means, this question can't be answered. To find the average value of $f(n)$, for instance, one would typically start with $$\frac1x \sum_{n\le x} f(n) = \frac1x \sum_{p\le x} \frac{g(p)}p \biggl\lfloor \frac xp \biggr\rfloor.$$

Comment: @GregMartin I appreciate the comment! How would one best specify what a study of the closed form, arithmetic properties, relations to other functions, etc be if 'general study' isn't specific enough. (Similar to how one could use sums over divisors and study such properties'

Comment: Generally speaking one can study the sums on prime powers by introducing $\Lambda (d)/\log d$ and then if the sums on the prime squares, cubes etc is negligible one gets the sum on primes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a handful of tricks,

It is additive (not completely additivitive) in the sense that if $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then $f(mn)=f(m)+f(n)$.

Another identity you have is $f(n)=f(n^k)$ or more generally, $f(n)=f(\mathrm{rad}(n))$.

A well studied function of this form is: $\omega(n)=\sum_{p|n}1$, the number of distinct prime factors of $n$. I would look into either comparing any choice of $f$ against $\omega$ for creating things like inequalities or look at [identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function#Properties_and_relations) involving it, like $2^{\omega(n)}=\sum_{d|n}|\mu(d)|$ to try to see if any of the techniques also carry over to your case.

Since $g(p)$ over $p$ is superfluous because it maps into $\mathbb{C}$, you likely have more structure to work with if you can elaborate on why that is a convenient choice.

---

Furthermore, it appears if we define $h(p)=1-e^\frac{g(p)}{p}$ then we have,

$$f(n)=\sum_{p|n}\ln(1-h(p))$$
$$e^{f(n)}=\prod_{p|n}(1-h(p))=\prod_{p|n}\sum_{i=0}^{v_p(n)}\mu(p^i)h(p^i)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)h(d)$$

Here I've extended $h(1)=1$ and $h(p^i)$ for $i>1$ may be arbitrary, since it multiplies $\mu(p^i)=0$ and we get a multiplicative function $h$ for free from the resulting $h(n)=\prod_{p|n}h(p^{v_p(n)})$. Note that we also have that $e^{f(n)}$ is a multiplicative function. You might want to work with that directly, then unravel it back out to the original function after determining any kind of asymptotics for instance.

$$f(n)=\ln\left(\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\left(1-e^\frac{g(d)}{d}\right)\right)$$

---

Worked example:

We can't really plug in any choices of $g$, since it has to be consistent with $h(p)$ and picking $h(1)=1$ and translating this to $g$. $h(1)=1-e^{g(1)/1}$ means we'd be be forced into extending it to picking $g(1)=-\infty \ne 1$, and similarly $h(6)=h(2)h(3)=(1-e^{g(2)/2})(1-e^{g(3)/3}) = 1-e^{g(6)/6}$ makes $$g(6)=6\ln(1-(1-e^{g(2)/2})(1-e^{g(3)/3}))$$.

I'll admit that looks a little gross, but this is the shadow of our perfectly nice multiplicative function $h$ that extends our function $g$ defined on primes to all squarefree numbers uniquely.

Picking $g(n)=\phi(n)$ really only means we're picking $g(p)=p-1$ because $g$ is only defined on primes. The rest of $g$ is determined through how it feeds into $h$ as described just above. So if we now try to compute this formula with $f(12)$ in both ways,

$$f(12)=\sum_{p|12}\frac{p-1}{p} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{3}=\frac{7}{6}$$

$$e^{f(12)}=\sum_{d|12}\mu(d)\left(1-e^\frac{g(d)}{d}\right)$$
(Since $\mu(n)=0$ for non-squarefree numbers I've omitted those terms)
$$=\left(1-e^\frac{g(1)}{1}\right) - \left(1-e^\frac{g(2)}{2}\right) - \left(1-e^\frac{g(3)}{3}\right) + \left(1-e^\frac{g(6)}{6}\right)$$
$$=1 - \left(1-e^\frac{g(2)}{2}\right) - \left(1-e^\frac{g(3)}{3}\right) + \left(1-e^\frac{g(2)}{2}\right)\left(1-e^\frac{g(3)}{3}\right)$$
$$=e^{\frac{g(2)}{2}+\frac{g(3)}{3}}=e^\frac{7}{6}$$

Hopefully that clears up that while $h$ is an arbitrary multiplicative function, it doesn't mean $g$ can be chosen so arbitrarily for its behavior outside primes, as it is typically (always?) not a multiplicative function even on squarefree numbers.

Comment: This is a nice answer! Thanks

Comment: Yup you're welcome, I had fun thinking about it this afternoon.

Comment: Not sure if I'm making a mistake, but putting $g(p) = \phi(p)$ and using
$$e^{f(n)}=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)h(d)$$
yields a contradiction on the LHS and RHS... 
Are you sure the 1st $\rightarrow$ 2nd line in the equation of $e^{f(n)}$ is what it's supposed to be? If so then what am I potentially missing?

Comment: @Mako I've just edited my answer working through your example in a bit of detail to help show what I suspect went wrong; let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: thanks for the worked example. I just don't really understand how if we define $g(n)=\phi(n)$ then $$\left(1-e^{\frac{\phi(6)}{6}}\right) \neq \left(1-e^{\frac{\phi(2)}{2}}\right)\left(1-e^{\frac{\phi(3)}{3}}\right)$$

Perhaps a better pick for $g(n)$ would be something that makes $f(n)$ completely additive(?) It still doesn't seem to work unless I'm missing something...

Comment: The problem is $g(6)$ is determined by $g(2)$ and $g(3)$ through the identity $h(6)=h(2)h(3)$. We can't pick it to be anything, since it's forced by $h$ being multiplicative, specifically that leads to: $g(6)=6\ln(1-(1-e^{g(2)/2})(1-e^{g(3)/3}))$. This is allowed because $g$ is really only defined on primes to begin with, and by choosing this specific way of extending to composite numbers (really just squarefree numbers is restricted) this lets us write it in this way.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. Seeing that one of your specialties is p-adic number theory. What techniques would you suggest for studying, for example $$\sum_{p\mid n}\frac{v_p(n)}{p}$$
where $v_p(n)$ is the p-adic valuation